# QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout “” to QWidget “”, which already has a layout

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qwidget, qmainwindow

I have an issue with my PyQt setup. Whenever I load my script, I got this message popping.

`QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to Ingest "Ingest", which already has a layout`

That's my first time trying to implement a Promoted Widget and I'm not very experimented yet with PyQt. Essentially, I'm loading my 'MainWindow', which gets its promoted widget 'Ingest'.
I've done my interfaces using QtDesigner and I convert my .ui using pyuic4 into .py.

The main problem looks to be somewhere between my promoted tab "Ingest" and the "Ingest" widget itself. 
Your help will be very appreciated!

Here's my whole thing (stripped of all the unrelated commands). Please don't mind if it's a little bit messy.

First, my opening script:

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

from python.mainwindow import MainWindow

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.processEvents()

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This calls my MainWindow script.

MainWindow class:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from .ui.mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
from styleSheets import styleSheets
import some_other_imports

class MainWindow(QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowTitle("Project Manager")
        #self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("some/path/icon.png"))

        #self.some_other_commands('foo')

        #self.this_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)


    def some_other_commands(self,some_arg):
        return  some_arg
```

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.resize(948, 540)
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(948, 540))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(948, 16777215))
        MainWindow.setDockOptions(QtGui.QMainWindow.AllowTabbedDocks|QtGui.QMainWindow.AnimatedDocks)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self.tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tabWidget"))

        # PROJECT TAB
        self.project_tab = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.project_tab.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("project_tab"))
        self.gridLayout_5 = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.project_tab)
        self.gridLayout_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout_5"))
        spacerItem = QtGui.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_5.addItem(spacerItem, 2, 3, 1, 1)
        self.projects_listWidget = QtGui.QListWidget(self.project_tab)
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.projects_listWidget, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.project_tab, _fromUtf8(""))

        # SEQ/SHOT TAB
        self.seqshots_tab = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.seqshots_tab.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("seqshots_tab"))
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.seqshots_tab)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout_2"))
        self.treeWidget = QtGui.QTreeWidget(self.seqshots_tab)
        self.treeWidget.setAnimated(True)
        self.treeWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("treeWidget"))
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.treeWidget, 1, 0, 1, 4)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.seqshots_tab, _fromUtf8(""))

        # INGEST TAB
        # *** PROBLEMATIC TAB ***
        self.ingest_tab = Ingest(self.tabWidget)
        self.ingest_tab.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("ingest_tab"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.ingest_tab, _fromUtf8(""))

        # SETTINGS TAB
        self.settings_tab = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.settings_tab.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("settings_tab"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.settings_tab, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 0, 1, 1, 1)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Project Manager", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.project_tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Project", None))
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Items", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.seqshots_tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Seq / Shots", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.ingest_tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Ingest", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.settings_tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Settings", None))

from ..ingest import Ingest

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This Ui_MainWindow interface calls the promoted tab 'Ingest'.

And now for the main course, my 'Ingest' widget:

```
import os,sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from .ui.ingest import Ui_Ingest

class Ingest(QMainWindow,Ui_Ingest):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(Ingest,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Ingest Tools")

        #self.button.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.some_command)

    def some_command(self):
        return "foo"
```

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Ingest(object):
    def setupUi(self, Ingest):
        Ingest.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Ingest"))
        Ingest.resize(686, 374)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(Ingest)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
        self.splitter = QtGui.QSplitter(Ingest)
        self.splitter.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.splitter.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("splitter"))
        self.widget = QtGui.QWidget(self.splitter)
        self.widget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("widget"))
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.widget)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout_2"))
        self.ingest_project_group = QtGui.QGroupBox(self.widget)
        self.ingest_project_group.setTitle(_fromUtf8("Projects"))
        self.ingest_project_group.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("ingest_project_group"))
        self.gridLayout_7 = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.ingest_project_group)
        self.gridLayout_7.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout_7"))
        self.ingest_project_comboBox = QtGui.QComboBox(self.ingest_project_group)
        self.ingest_project_comboBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("ingest_project_comboBox"))
        self.gridLayout_7.addWidget(self.ingest_project_comboBox, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.ingest_project_group, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.ingest_data_group = QtGui.QGroupBox(self.widget)
        self.ingest_data_group.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(209, 0))
        self.ingest_data_group.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(209, 16777215))
        self.ingest_data_group.setTitle(_fromUtf8("Data"))
        self.ingest_data_group.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("ingest_data_group"))
        self.gridLayout_4 = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.ingest_data_group)
        self.gridLayout_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout_4"))
        self.ingest_path = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.ingest_data_group)
        self.ingest_path.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 25))
        self.ingest_path.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.ingest_path.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("ingest_path"))
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.ingest_path, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.ingest_path_button = QtGui.QPushButton(self.ingest_data_group)
        self.ingest_path_button.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(25, 0))
        self.ingest_path_button.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(25, 16777215))
        self.ingest_path_button.setText(_fromUtf8("..."))
        self.ingest_path_button.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("ingest_path_button"))
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.ingest_path_button, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.ingest_resolutionFolder_checkBox = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.ingest_data_group)
        self.ingest_resolutionFolder_checkBox.setToolTip(_fromUtf8("<html><head/><body><p>Check it if there is a resolution folder in each shots.</p><p>Example: [...]/19TWO_VFX_2001-01-01/19TWO_042_010/<span style=\" font-weight:600; text-decoration: underline;\">2048x1152</span>/frame.1001.dpx<br/></p></body></html>"))
        self.ingest_resolutionFolder_checkBox.setText(_fromUtf8("Resolution Folder"))
        self.ingest_resolutionFolder_checkBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("ingest_resolutionFolder_checkBox"))
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.ingest_resolutionFolder_checkBox, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.ingest_getData_button = QtGui.QCommandLinkButton(self.ingest_data_group)
        self.ingest_getData_button.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(150, 16777215))
        self.ingest_getData_button.setText(_fromUtf8("Refresh Datas"))
        self.ingest_getData_button.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("ingest_getData_button"))
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.ingest_getData_button, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        spacerItem = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout_4.addItem(spacerItem, 7, 0, 1, 1)
        self.ingest_update_in_FS_button = QtGui.QCommandLinkButton(self.ingest_data_group)
        self.ingest_update_in_FS_button.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(150, 16777215))
        self.ingest_update_in_FS_button.setText(_fromUtf8("Update \'in FS\'"))
        self.ingest_update_in_FS_button.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("ingest_update_in_FS_button"))
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.ingest_update_in_FS_button, 8, 0, 1, 1)
        self.ingest_nameMatchCode = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.ingest_data_group)
        self.ingest_nameMatchCode.setToolTip(_fromUtf8("<html><head/><body><p>&quot;</p><p>Use flags to return a naming convention when naming the files or folders in a project. Always separate the flags with underscors ( _ ).<br/>example: &lt;proj&gt;_&lt;0&gt;_&lt;seq&gt;_&lt;shot&gt;</p><p>FLAGS<br/>&lt;0&gt; : Null info. Put this if there\'s a place with nothing to get.<br/>&lt;proj&gt; : Indicates the abreviation or name of the project. <br/>&lt;seq&gt; : Gets the name of the sequence. Insert this multiple times if the sequence has multiple sections.<br/>&lt;shot&gt; : Gets the name of the shot. Insert this multiple times if the shot has multiple sections.</p><p>&quot;</p></body></html>"))
        self.ingest_nameMatchCode.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.ingest_nameMatchCode.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("ingest_nameMatchCode"))
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.ingest_nameMatchCode, 4, 0, 1, 2)
        self.ingest_nameMatchCode_label = QtGui.QLabel(self.ingest_data_group)
        self.ingest_nameMatchCode_label.setText(_fromUtf8("Name Match Code:"))
        self.ingest_nameMatchCode_label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("ingest_nameMatchCode_label"))
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.ingest_nameMatchCode_label, 3, 0, 1, 2)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.ingest_data_group, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.ingest_shot_table = QtGui.QTableWidget(self.splitter)
        self.ingest_shot_table.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(250, 0))
        self.ingest_shot_table.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("ingest_shot_table"))
        self.ingest_shot_table.setColumnCount(0)
        self.ingest_shot_table.setRowCount(0)
        self.widget1 = QtGui.QWidget(self.splitter)
        self.widget1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("widget1"))
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.widget1)
        self.verticalLayout.setMargin(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.widget1)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        spacerItem1 = QtGui.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.splitter)

        self.retranslateUi(Ingest)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Ingest)

    def retranslateUi(self, Ingest):
        Ingest.setWindowTitle(_translate("Ingest", "Form", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Ingest", "PushButton", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Ingest = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Ingest()
    ui.setupUi(Ingest)
    Ingest.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: change `class Ingest(QMainWindow,Ui_Ingest):` to `class Ingest(QWidget,Ui_Ingest):`

Comment: Thanks! This solved my issue! Such a simple solution to a very basic problem.